# How to extend two Angular class components in third component class?

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, angular5, mixins

I have some functionality Where I have two separate component classes such as Class Component A and Class Component B. And I wanted to extends those in the Class Component C.

I heard that I can take help from Mixin in Angular typescript but not sure How to use it in Component classes. It would be helpful if there is any way we can achieve same in the angular.

I have also checked the example mentioned here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mixin-example

I have also Tried applyMixins as below but not able to work it out in Class components.

```
class A {
    start() {
        console.log('Vehicle Started');
    }
}

class B {
    end() {
        console.log('Vehicle stopped');
    }
}


class C implements A, B {
    end(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }

    start(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}

applyMixins(C, [A, B])
```

Comment: Have you tried extends instead of implements? extends is for inheritance and implements is for interfaces.

Comment: From my personal view mutliple inheritance is a bad approach. I believe there is a better way. Why are you trying to inherit from 2 other components? Maybe you need a service you can inject?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why do you want to do this, but I manage to make it work thus:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-typescript-mixins

In a few words I wrapped the function *applyMixins* into a file

```
export function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
             if (name !== 'constructor') {
                derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Later in component **C** I implemented the component **A** and **B** and finally called the function inside the constructor:

```
export class CComponent implements AComponent, BComponent {
    
    end(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }

    start(): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }

    constructor() {
      applyMixins(CComponent,[AComponent,BComponent])
    }
}
```